# How to make a repeated string to the left be deleted without using While?

Tags: ruby

For example, I have this string of **only numbers**:

`0009102`

If I convert it to integer Ruby automatically gives me this value:

`9102`

That's correct. But my program gives me different types of numbers:

`2229102` desired output => `9102`

`9999102` desired output => `102`

If you look at them I have treated `2` and `9` as zeros since they are automatically deleted, well, it is easy to delete that with an `while` but I must avoid it.

In other words, how do you make 'n' on the left be considered a zero for Ruby?

Comment: Do you always want to remove the frist three characters? Or only if they are the same? Or do you only want to remove `2` and `9` prefixes? What is the number is `'2222222'`? Should that output `0` or `2222`? Please elaborate.

Comment: I forgot to say, yes, the length is dynamic not just three characters. 'n' can be any character from 0 to 9, is not limited to 2 and 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"2229102".sub(/\A(\d)\1*/, "") #=> "9102"`.
```

The regular expression reads, "match the first digit in the string (`\A` is the beginning-of-string anchor) in capture group 1 (`(\d)`), followed by zero or more characters (`*`) that equal the contents of capture group 1 (`\1`). [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) converts that match to an empty string.

Comment: It's there. You don't see it? Actually, I originally had it there, but after testing I wanted to make sure it was needed, so I tested without the anchor, which confirmed my original answer. Unfortunately, I forgot to put the anchor back in.

Comment: How would it be in case the string is letters and numbers and I just want to delete the first character repeated?

Comment: Change `(\d)` to `(.)`. Nothing more. `.` matches any character. `\1` still matches the contents of capture group 1.

Comment: Thanks for the checkmark, but you may wish to retract it, at least for now. The problem is that quick selections often discourage other answers. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection, some wait a full day to give members around the world a chance to answer. There's no rush.

Comment: What if I just want for a specific character?

Comment: Okay, I'll withdraw the checkmark, and then I'll check it out.

Comment: Were that character an exclamation mark, say, replace `(\d)` with `(!)`.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's what I did, but I made the mistake of putting it in quotation marks.

Comment: If you had `str = "Charlie ChaplinCharlie ChaplinCharlie Chaplin123"`, then `str.gsub(/\A(Charlie Chaplin)\1*/, "") #=> "123"`.

Comment: Thank you, just one last thing, if I want to replace from right to left, what would it be like?

Comment: There is no need to `gsub` here, `sub` would be enough.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, what was I thinking? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Enumerable#chunk_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while):

```
s = '222910222'

s.each_char.chunk_while(&:==).drop(1).join
#=> "910222"
```

Where `s.each_char.chunk_while(&:==).to_a #=> [["2", "2", "2"], ["9"], ["1"], ["0"], ["2", "2", "2"]]`

Comment: Thank you, but you missed the 9. `to_a[1..9]`

Comment: I think you meant to use `each_char`, to avoid the intermediate array produced by `chars`. :-) The rule: use `chars` to produce a receiver for an `Array` method; otherwise use `each_char`.

Comment: @talC, not required, see endless range: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges

Comment: But Ruby gives me error, only adding the 9 works for me.

Comment: @talC Ok, maybe you are using an older Ruby version. So, use `[1..-1]` instead, since you don't know how many elements are in the array: `[0,2,4,6][1..-1] #=> [2, 4, 6]`

Comment: Alternatively you could also use `.drop(1)` instead of `.to_a[1..]` which drops one element and returns the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the [solution of iGian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58461471/3982562) you could also use [`drop_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop_while).

```
s = '222910222'

s.each_char.each_cons(2).drop_while { |a, b| a == b }.map(&:last).join
#=> "910222"

# or

s.each_char.drop_while.with_index(-1) { |c, i| i < 0 || c == s[i] }.join
#=> "910222"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way:

```
s = '9999102938'

s.chars.then{ |chars| chars[chars.index(chars.uniq[1])..-1] }.join
=> "102938"
```